# How to store combobox selected item in SQL Server database

Tags: java, combobox

Everything is going to be fine here, but it isn't getting selected text in combobox.

I've read articles in Stack Overflow but it's not working at all. I wonder if the issue is where the submit entry button (in `actionevent`) below `cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem())`. I am getting a `java.lang.nullpointerexception` here.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Pay implements ActionListener
    {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9;
    JTabbedPane t1;
    JLabel idLabel,oneidLabel,nameLabel,addressLabel;
    JLabel cityLabel,stateLabel,phoneLabel,itemLabel,pincodeLabel;
    JTable dataTable;
    JTextField idField,oneidField,nameField,addressField,cityField; 
    JTextField stateField,phoneField,itemField,pincodeField;
    JButton entryButton,accessButton,submitentryButton,accessrecordButton;
    JComboBox mainBox;
     Font onefont,twofont;
     String post[]={"Student","Staff"};
     //JTable dataTable,staffTable,onedataTable,onestaffTable;
     JScrollPane dataScroll,staffScroll,onedataScroll,onestaffScroll;
     GridBagLayout gbl,onegbl,twogbl;
     GridBagConstraints gbc,onegbc,twogbc;

     public Pay() 
     {
        frame=new JFrame("sample");
       p1=new JPanel();
       p2=new JPanel();
       p3=new JPanel();
    
      p4=new JPanel();
    
    //p7=new JPanel();
    onefont=new Font("Rosemary",Font.BOLD,14);
    
    entryButton=new JButton("Entry");
    entryButton.setFont(onefont);
    accessButton=new JButton("Access");
    accessButton.setFont(onefont);
    submitentryButton=new JButton("Submit Entry");
    submitentryButton.setFont(onefont);
    accessrecordButton=new JButton("Access Record");
    accessrecordButton.setFont(onefont);
    //addstaffButton=new JButton("Add Staff");

        idLabel=new JLabel("Consumer ID");
       idLabel.setFont(onefont);
        nameLabel=new JLabel("Consumer Name");
       nameLabel.setFont(onefont);
       addressLabel=new JLabel("Address");
        addressLabel.setFont(onefont);
        cityLabel=new JLabel("City");
        cityLabel.setFont(onefont);
        stateLabel=new JLabel("State");
        stateLabel.setFont(onefont);
        phoneLabel=new JLabel("Enter Phone : ");
        phoneLabel.setFont(onefont);
        itemLabel=new JLabel("Item");
        itemLabel.setFont(onefont);
        pincodeLabel=new JLabel("PINCODE");
         pincodeLabel.setFont(onefont);

    
        oneidLabel=new JLabel("Consumer ID");
        oneidLabel.setFont(onefont);

    
    
       idField=new JTextField(10);
       nameField=new JTextField(10);
        addressField=new JTextField(10);
         cityField=new JTextField(10);
        stateField=new JTextField(10);
        pincodeField=new JTextField(10);
         itemField=new JTextField(10);
        //=new JTextField(10);
    
    
         oneidField=new JTextField(10);
    
    
    


        //code separation
        gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
         gbl=new GridBagLayout();
         p1.setLayout(gbl);
         gbc.insets=new Insets(4,4,4,4);
         gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    
         gbc.gridx=0;
         gbc.gridy=0;
         gbl.setConstraints(idLabel,gbc);
    
         gbc.gridx=1;
         gbc.gridy=0;
         gbl.setConstraints(idField,gbc);
    
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbl.setConstraints(nameLabel,gbc);
    
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbl.setConstraints(nameField,gbc);
    
       gbc.gridx=0;
       gbc.gridy=2;
       gbl.setConstraints(addressLabel,gbc);
    
       gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=2;
       gbl.setConstraints(addressField,gbc);
    
       gbc.gridx=0;
       gbc.gridy=3;
       gbl.setConstraints(cityLabel,gbc);
       gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=3;
       gbl.setConstraints(cityField,gbc);
    
       gbc.gridx=0;
       gbc.gridy=4;
       gbl.setConstraints(stateLabel,gbc);
      gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=4;
       gbl.setConstraints(stateField,gbc);
    
       gbc.gridx=0;
      gbc.gridy=5;
       gbl.setConstraints(pincodeLabel,gbc);
       gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=5;
      gbl.setConstraints(pincodeField,gbc);
    
       //combobox
          String intake[]={"Shoes","Flip-Flop","Sandals","Formal"};
       JComboBox mainBox=new JComboBox(intake);
        mainBox.setFont(onefont);
    
       gbc.gridx=0;
       gbc.gridy=6;
       gbl.setConstraints(itemLabel,gbc);
       gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=6;
        gbl.setConstraints(mainBox,gbc);
    
    
       gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=7;
       gbl.setConstraints(submitentryButton,gbc);

        p2.setLayout(null);
     
       oneidLabel.setBounds(0,0,150,70);
    

       oneidField.setBounds(90,25,150,25);

      accessrecordButton.setBounds(240,20,150,30);
    
      dataTable=new JTable(100,7);
      dataScroll=new JScrollPane(dataTable);

     
     // column headers were there but i didn't added them because of text
    //settings
    //dataTable.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue
     


       dataScroll.setBounds(10,60,490,400);

         p1.add(idLabel);
        p1.add(idField);
        p1.add(nameLabel);
        p1.add(nameField);
        p1.add(addressLabel);
        p1.add(addressField);
        p1.add(cityLabel);
        p1.add(cityField);
        p1.add(stateLabel);
        p1.add(stateField);
        p1.add(pincodeLabel);
        p1.add(pincodeField);
        p1.add(itemLabel);
        p1.add(mainBox);
        p1.add(submitentryButton);

    
        p2.add(oneidLabel);
        p2.add(oneidField);
        p2.add(accessrecordButton);
        p2.add(dataScroll);


        Font font=new Font("Rosemary",Font.BOLD,32);
       //headingLabel.setFont(font);
        //headingLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        t1=new JTabbedPane();
        t1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        Font tfont=new Font("Rosemary",Font.BOLD,15);
         t1.setFont(tfont);

    
    
         submitentryButton.addActionListener(this);
         accessrecordButton.addActionListener(this);
    
    
         Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
         Dimension d=t.getScreenSize();
         frame.setLocation((d.width-400)/2,(d.height-400)/2);
    
    
         t1.addTab("Entry",p1);  
        t1.addTab("Access", p2);
      
        frame.add(t1);
        frame.setSize(520,520);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
          {
            new Pay();
          }

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
         {
         if(evt.getSource()==entryButton)
        {
        //p1.add( p3);
        
        
        //p1.revalidate();
        
        
        
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        
        
       }
       if(evt.getSource()==accessButton)
       {
        //String row[]={"","","","","",};
        
        //p5=new JPanel();
        //p5.add(dataScroll);
        //p2.add(p4);
        //p2.revalidate();
        p2.setVisible(true);
        p1.setVisible(false);
        }
    
       if(evt.getSource()==submitentryButton)
        {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StudentDSN");
    CallableStatement cl=con.prepareCall("{call firstone(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
            cl.setString(1,idField.getText());
            cl.setString(2,nameField.getText());
            
            cl.setString(3,addressField.getText());
            cl.setString(4,cityField.getText());
            cl.setString(5,stateField.getText());
        
            
            cl.setString(6,pincodeField.getText());
            //String x = String.valueOf(mainBox.getSelectedItem());
            //cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem());
            cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem());
        
            cl.registerOutParameter(8, Types.INTEGER);
            cl.executeUpdate();
            
            int i=cl.getInt(8);
            
            if(i==1)
            {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Record successfully stored"); 
            }
            else
            {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"consumer is already..");
            }
          }
              catch (Exception e) 
           {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e+"");
           }
          }
          if(evt.getSource()==accessrecordButton)
           {
           try
           {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            
           Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StudentDSN");
            CallableStatement cl=con.prepareCall("{call secondone}"); 
            
            ResultSet rs=cl.executeQuery();
            int i=0;
            
            while(rs.next())
             {
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(2),i,0);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(3),i,1);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(4),i,2);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(5),i,3);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(6),i,4);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(7),i,5);
                dataTable.setValueAt(rs.getString(8),i,6);
                i++;
            }
          }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e+"");
            
         }
        }
         }
```

Comment: First, remove this `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e+"");` then add `printStacktrace(e)` then tell us what your error message is.

Comment: it's not working why don't you try at urself once.  i've pasted program above

Comment: i think problem is arising here  cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem()); m a beginner, i don't know that much.plz help me to get rid of it

Comment: Sorry for `printStacktrace(e)` it should be `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: *i think problem is arising here cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem());* is it nullpointer exception?

Comment: yupz it shows java.lang.nullpointerexception,somehow problem is arising here cl.setObject(7,mainBox.getSelectedItem());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have declared `JComboBox` as a member variable of class.

```
JComboBox mainBox;
```

Then in below line instead initialized it, you have created new instance of `JComboBox`:

```
JComboBox mainBox=new JComboBox(intake);
```

So, as a solution change above line to:

```
mainBox=new JComboBox(intake);
```

One last thing, instead of keeping `JComboBox mainBox;` as [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) make it `JComboBox<String> mainBox;` and then you need to add [the diamond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) to below line also:

```
mainBox=new JComboBox<>(intake);
```

To get clear idea about this, [read about generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).